# How to filter by a selectedvalue all in the same table with DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

In PowerBI I'm having this problem:

```
ID  ---- Father ---- Sales <br>
1   ---- 0      ---- 8.70  <br>
2   ---- 1      ---- 7.70  <br>
3   ---- 2      ---- 4.50  <br>
4   ---- 2      ---- 3.20  <br>
5   ---- 1      ---- 1.00
```

As you can see this is a hierarchy, father with ID equals to 2 has 2 children, ID 3 and 4. At the same time father 2 is child of ID 1, and this last has no father. I want to group total sales by this hierarchy, that is:

ID (2) = $4.50 (2) + $3.20 (3) = 7.70 
ID (1) = ID(2) + ID(5) = 8.70

So for this problem I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
VAR sel = SELECTEDVALUE('public cuentasbal_t'[cod_cuentabal])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM('public cuentasbal_t'[cod_cuentabal]),
    FILTER(
        'public cuentasbal_t',
        'public cuentasbal_t'[padre] = sel
    )
)
```

But this doesn't work. Any idea? Thank you so much un advance.

Comment: This is not supported, please have a look at: https://www.daxpatterns.com/parent-child-hierarchies/

Comment: In the website you provide, they don't show the DAX for the variables BrowseDepth and MaxNodeDepth. Do you know how to get them? Sorry but I'm new in DAX. @Aldert